# PhpStorm: Log tab (Version control) doesn't show changed files

Tags: phpstorm, commit, jetbrains-ide

I don't know exactly what happened but somehow now when I go to the *Log* tab on the **Version control** menu at the bottom in PhpStorm and select a commit, I cannot see the files changed in that commit anymore, just the text for the commit.

I somehow deactivated that by typing some command by mistake in my keyboard and now I cannot figure out how to put it back.

Thanks in advance ;)

Comment: A wild guess: try dragging the upper side of the window: https://i.gyazo.com/44a578e9804f32cc71fbb4dd5786db79.mp4. If that doesn't help - please attach a screenshot of your layout

Comment: @Ástþór a wild guess was all I needed to solve this problem apparently. Thanks a lot! I couldn't see any sign of a something being hidden there. Now I know. Again, thanks a lot!